# I can not install the Pygame module

Tags: python, pygame, python-module

I tried to install pygame module but first I needed to update my pip, so I did it via this code

```
 pip install --upgrade pip
```

then I tried to install pygame with this code

```
pip3 install pygame
```

And

```
pip install pygame
```

once I did that it gave me an error message starting with

```
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8
```

tried to install other modules and it went just fine.

I use vs code and I use a MacBook.

Comment: We need more information likw what os and version of python you are running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: Pygame might not be compatible with Python 3.8, try other versions of Python

Depending on if you are using Linux distros or MacOS, a '**sudo**' might be needed at the start.

Try installing pygame with just '**pip**' instead of '**pip3**'.

Answer (score 0):

If you use PyCharm, you can easily install most libraries from there. Setting PyCharm up is slightly complicated though.